# Caught Error error while using useEffect react native HOOks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation, react-dom, react-async

so i am trying to use async storage and trying to validate if their is data in Async or not..
[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGgSk.png)
[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIGnO.jpg)

i am not able to validate through...

Comment: Please include your code as text instead of an image to preserve the used code for a later date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move calling the hook outside of your code

```
   const readData = ...


   useEffect(() => {
     const timeout = setTimeout(() => readData(), 5000)
     return () => { clearTimeout(timeout) }
   }, [])
```

Next time post code questions with code.